# How to synchronize source and destination folders when destination contains only NTFS hard links

Tags: windows, ntfs, data-synchronization

We have source "S" folder,  destination "D" and Original "O".

D is a copy of O using NTFS hard link for all files.

Now we need to synchronize S and D and copy only changed files from S to D.

Robocopy.exe does that, however it overwrites files and as a result files are changed in both D and O, but we want files in O to remain intact, no matter what.

To correctly update hard link copy one needs to delete file in D (in order to break the link) and then create file with the same name instead of override.

Does robocopy supports that? Perhaps there is a special parameter for that, or is there any other free utility (preferable open source) that knows how to correctly update file if it's a hard link?

Comment: There is **nothing** that makes a one instance of a file a "hardlink" while making the other one the "original". They are *both* 'first-class' -- neither is secondary, neither to the operating system nor to you. Keep this in mind when saying a folder "only" contains hard links, because those are the files *themselves*, no question!

Comment: Copy D to D2, delete D, rename D2 to D.  And in future, don't use hard links.

Comment: Mehrdad, thanks, after posting a question I realized that both files (one in O and one in D) are hard links and since I need a tool to always do it in the following way: create temp file, delete original, rename temp to original behavior.

Comment: Harry,

Due to specifics of our requirement copy from O to D should be as quick as possible, if folder is ~20Gb or more copy operation takes too much time, that's why we use hardlinks.

Also this way we can store multiple versions of O (in D1, D2, D3,... Dn) and it will be very space efficient.

Comment: That's all very well, but one day someone will carelessly edit or overwrite one of the files in Dn and be very cross doing so broke O and D1 through D(n-1).  Hard links just aren't a good mechanism for dealing with mutable files.  You should probably investigate using Single Instance Storage instead.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
I didn't want to include too many details in original question, but we need to support simultaneous update from S to D and simultaneous downloads from D to clients. Having only single instance would mean we need to block either write or read operation.

I understand the risk of having someone accidentally overwriting file in Dn and this way breaking it in D1...Dn-1 as well, but it's internal storage and access to share is very limited.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant by Single Instance Storage.  Start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg232683%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I didn't have opportunity to review it in details, but from the first sight it doesn't seem like a solution.

Imagine that we have multiple clients downloading files from D, and at the same time we want to upload new version.

Does SIS allows to do it without blocking? And does it guarantee clients will never get intermediate results (dirty read) from D?

Because with hard links we solve it by creating new version D2 and allowing uploader to copy files there without affecting clients that download from D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using rsync - see this post for details, including readymade backup scripts:

[How to create rsync-like hard link backups with VSS on Windows](http://blog.jay2k1.com/2011/08/13/how-to-create-rsync-like-hard-link-backups-with-vss-on-windows/)